# On Some Properties of Hölder Continuous Functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, holder-spaces

The function space $H^{\alpha} (\Omega)$ for $0 < \alpha \le 1$,  is the set of functions:

$$\{ f \in C^0(\Omega) : \sup_{x \neq y} \dfrac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} < \infty \}$$

with the metric $d_{H^{\alpha}} = || f - g ||_{H^{\alpha}}$, where 
$$||f||_{H^{\alpha}} = ||f||_{sup} + [f]_{H^{\alpha}} \text{ ,        } [f]_{H^{\alpha}} = \sup_{x \neq y}  \dfrac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} $$

Now, if $0 < \alpha < \beta \le 1$, then

$$[f]_{H^{\alpha}} \le 2 ||f||_{sup}^{1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}  [f]_{H^{\beta}}^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} \space \forall f \in H^{\beta}$$

And also, there is some constant $M$ so that:

$$||f||_{H^{\alpha}} \le M ||f||_{sup}^{1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}}  ||f||_{H^{\beta}}^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} \space \forall f \in H^{\beta}$$

These were some questions on a problem set: I have checked that $d_{H^{\alpha}}$ is a metric, and proved the two properties (in the second I found that $M = 2$ is sufficient). However, rather blindly. It's easy to show from the first that if $0 < \alpha < \beta \le 1$, then $H^{\beta} \subset H^{\alpha}$.

What else do these formulas mean? Are they just some useful inequalities, or do they establish some connection between $H^{\beta}$ and $H^{\alpha}$?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the $\alpha$ is on both sides in the first inequality?  In the second?

Comment: Yes indeed! I'm so sorry, copy and paste with all the repetition...

Comment: [this article](http://www.jstor.org/pss/2243741?searchUrl=/action/doBasicSearch%3FQuery%3Dau%253A%2522R.%2BV.%2BErickson%2522%26wc%3Don%26acc%3Doff&Search=yes) might be of interest. It deals a lot of inclusion of one Holder space into another, and gives an application of such inclusions. The main point is the same as given by Willie Wong --  precompactness.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Those two final inequalities are known as "interpolation inequalities". The point being the following: you can "extend" the Holder norms to $\alpha = 0$ with the formal expression

$$ [ f ]_{H^0} = \sup_{x\neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^0} = \sup_{x\neq y} \frac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{1} \leq 2 [f]_{sup} $$

Or, in other words, you identify $H^0$ with $C^0$ equipped with the sup norm. As you observed, it gives you that $H^\alpha \subset H^\beta$ if $\alpha > \beta$. What's more, however, is that now, using the sup-norm factor in the interpolation inequality, you can use Arzela-Ascoli to show that the inclusion of $H^\alpha\subset H^\beta$ is pre-compact! That is, any bounded sequence in $H^\alpha$ would have a converging subsequence in $H^\beta$, for $\beta < \alpha$.

I think you understand how, whenever something allows you to extract a converging subsequence, it is very useful in analysis indeed.

Lastly, the expression illustrates a phenomenon that [happens with regularity in classical analysis](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/), which is that *good* "scales" of function spaces are often log-convex in the exponent. Your family of Holder space norms $H^\alpha$, parametrized by $\alpha$, by your two inequalities, is log-convex.

There presumably are very nice applications of the log convexity in interpolation theory etc for the Hölder spaces, but unfortunately none comes to mind immediately at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

I wish I could comment...

Anyway, I don't think the second inequality holds at all, for instance all constant functions violate it, and even taking these out will not solve the problem; for example: Assume the inequality holds, take $f\in H^\beta$, $f\geq 0$ and $c>0$, then since the seminorm doesn't see constants we get $(\| f\| _{sup} +c)^{\alpha /\beta} = \| f+c\| _{sup}^{\alpha / \beta} \leq M[f]_{\beta } ^{\alpha / \beta }$, and this is for all $c>0$.

Comment: What do you mean the seminorm doesn't see constants? If $f(x) = c$, then $[f]_{H^{\alpha}} = \sup_{x \neq y}  \dfrac{|f(x) - f(y)|}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} = \sup_{x \neq y}  \dfrac{0}{|x-y|^{\alpha}} = 0$. So if $f$ is constant, $||f||_{H^{\alpha}} = c + 0 = c$.

Comment: Then you get on the RHS $M \cdot c^{1- \frac{\alpha}{\beta}} \cdot c^{\frac{\alpha}{\beta}} = M \cdot c$, when $M = 2$, as far as I know, $c\le M\cdot c$.

Comment: If $f$ is constant the seminorm is zero, so the bound you get is $c\leq 0$. Why are you making one seminorm zero and the other one non-zero?

Comment: Oh Im so sorry! The very last $f$ is in a norm not seminorm. It's so hard to Latex this correctly!